# factory reset a device having no volume keys or home button

Tags: factory-reset

I got a device that I have to reset to factory settings because the owner of the device has forgotten its password. I checked Debugging is not enabled.

I have seen various suggestions on how to reset a device but all suggestion involve volume keys. Unfortunately this device doesn't have any volume or other key, there is just only one power key.

Device: QMobile E885

How do it reset it ? or unlock the device. any suggestions?

Comment: How the heck is possible that phone doesn't have volume buttons? Anyway try flashing stock firmware maybe there is way to do that without involving recovery

Answer (score 0):

There's instructions floating around for a QMobile E790, so this might work for your model.

Try dialing **277634#*#** or **47328545454#**
It should then give you the option to factory reset.